# How to use CORS correctly for Webflux, Spring-Security, okta-spring-boot-starter, and Okta-React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, spring-webflux, okta

I have a CORS webFilter in my webflux api and when I make an Options request via postman for the pre-flight checklist I get a response with the correct headers. But when I make the same request from a browser using Axios and the Okta-React library to retrieve the access token, a 401 Unauthorized is returned and the headers I am looking for are not returned. Is Axios not including the Bearer Token in the OPTIONS request? Do I need to whitelist options requests to not be authenticated by OKTA, wouldnt OKTA handle this?

I am using the same access token from the SPA in postman.
Am I missing something in the Axios request, is there any additional configuration I need to perform with Axios for CORS?

I am stumped, why does the webfilter activate for an OPTIONS request when sent from postman but not when called from Axios in the browser?

```js
const getExperience = () => {
        const { accessToken } = authState;

            axios({
                method: "get",
                timeout: 10000,
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                },
                url: `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/professionals`
            }).then( response => {
                setExperience(response.data);
            });
    }
```

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class CustomCorsWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private static final String ALLOWED_HEADERS = "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN";
    private static final String ALLOWED_METHODS = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    private static final String ALLOWED_ORIGIN = "http://localhost:3000";
    private static final String MAX_AGE = "3600";

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        if (exchange.getRequest().getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS);
            headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", MAX_AGE);
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ALLOWED_HEADERS);

            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I've used for setting CORS headers with [WebFlux, React, and Okta](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/25/spring-webflux-websockets-react).

```java
@Bean 
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("GET"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

I've also used a filter like the following:

```java
@Bean
CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
    corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("*");
    corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

    return new CorsWebFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: This works! So why does this work, and the filter does not?

Comment: I think the biggest difference is your filter is not setting allow credentials to be true. I added a filter example to my answer.

Comment: Ah that makes sense as to why I was getting an Unauthorized response due to the lack of the Authorization Header not being allowed. Learned something new today!

Comment: Just for clarification, when using RestControllers would you still need the `@CrossOrigin` annotation having used one of the above configuration choices?

Comment: No. You don't need `@CrossOrigin` when you configure it this way.